# Open accountdetails on button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have 2 pages; my index and my accountdetails. I have a button on my index page with the name "Account". Onclick it goes to the accountdetails page. Though, it doesn't retreive the information of the user into the form. How do I do that?

Index

```
<?php
session_start();
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "pc4u0fi_username";
$dbpass = "pc4upc4u1";
$dbname = "pc4u0fi_pc4u";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM Klanten WHERE ID = '".$_GET['wijzigen_id']."'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>PC4U</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">  </script>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("U bent succesvol uitgelogd");
}
</script>

<body>
<div id="container1">
<header>
    <div id="headerFotoDiv">
        <img src="images/logo.jpg" height="100px" class="lihover"
             onclick="window.location='http://www.pc4u.hexodo.nl/'">
    </div>
    <?php
    if ($_SESSION['ingelogd']) {
        ?>
        <div id="headerLogindiv">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick='location.href="?p=ac?wijzigen_id=<?= $row['ID'] ?>"'
                style="width: 130px; height:30px; margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 12px; text-align: center;">Account
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="window.location='?p=lo'"
                style="width: 130px; height:30px; margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 12px; text-align: center;">
            Uitloggen
        </button>
        </div>
        <?php
    } else {
        ?>
        <div id="headerLogindiv">
            <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="window.location='?p=i'"
                    style="width: 130px; height:30px; margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 12px; text-align: center;">
                Inloggen
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="window.location='?p=re'"
                    style="width: 130px; height:30px; margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 15px; text-align: center;">
                Registreren
            </button>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>

</header>
<!-- Static navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default"
     style="width: 1000px; margin-bottom:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-top:0px;border:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #000;border-radius:0px; background-color:#FFFFFF;"
     ;>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding:0px;">
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="true" style="height: 1px;padding:0px;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li onclick="document.location.href='http://www.pc4u.hexodo.nl/'" class="lihover"><a>Home</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                       aria-expanded="false">Computers
                        <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="?p=dp">PC</a></li>
                        <li><a href="?p=lp">Laptop</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="?p=r">Reparatie</a></li>
                <li><a href="?p=c">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="?p=w">Winkelwagen</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- Vulling van de pagina -->
<div id="vulling">
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
        $pagina = $_GET['p'];
        switch ($pagina) {
            case "c":
                include("contact.php");
                break;
            case "r":
                include("reparatie.php");
                break;
            case "re":
                include("registreren.php");
                break;
            case "i":
                include("inloggen.php");
                break;
            case "w":
                include("shoppingcart.php");
                break;
            case "ch":
                include("computerhome.php");
                break;
            case "lp":
                include("laptop.php");
                break;
            case "lo":
                include("logoutfrontend.php");
                break;
            case "ac":
                include("accountDetails.php");
                break;
            case "dp":
                include("desktop.php");
                break;
            default:
                include("home.php");
                break;
        }
    } else {
        include("home.php");
    }
    ?>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Accountdetails

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "pc4u0fi_username";
$dbpass = "pc4upc4u1";
$dbname = "pc4u0fi_pc4u";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$showalertsuccess = false;
$showalertdanger = false;

$retrieve = "SELECT * FROM Klanten WHERE ID = '".$_GET['wijzigen_id']."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $retrieve);
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$minion = $_GET['wijzigen_id'];

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$voornaam = $_POST['voornaam'];
$achternaam = $_POST['achternaam'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$woonplaats = $_POST['woonplaats'];
$postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
$straat = $_POST['straat'];
$huisnr = $_POST['huisnr'];
$telnr = $_POST['telnr'];

$query = "UPDATE Klanten SET klant_voornaam='$voornaam', klant_achternaam='$achternaam', klant_email='$email', klant_username='$username', klant_wachtwoord='$password', klant_woonplaats='$woonplaats', klant_postcode='$postcode', klant_straat='$straat', klant_huisnr='$huisnr', klant_telefoonnnummer='$telnr' WHERE ID = '".$_GET['wijzigen_id']."'";
}
?>
<h1 style="margin-left: 10px;">Uw gegevens</h1><br>
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" style="text-align: left; width: 120px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px;" for="vnaam">Voornaam:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vnaam" value="<?=$data['klant_voornaam'];?>" name="vnaam" style="width: 250px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 40px;" required placeholder="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="anaam" style="text-align: left; width: 120px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px;">Achternaam:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="anaam" value="<?=$data['klant_achternaam'];?>" name="anaam" style="width: 250px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 40px;" required placeholder="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" style="text-align: left; width: 120px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px;" for="email">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" value="<?=$data['klant_email'];?>" name="email" style="width: 250px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 40px;" required placeholder="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" style="text-align: left; width: 120px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px;" for="username">Username:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" value="<?=$data['klant_username'];?>" name="username" style="width: 250px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 40px;" required placeholder="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" style="text-align: left; width: 120px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px;" for="wachtwoord">Wachtwoord:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="wachtwoord" value="<?=$data['klant_wachtwoord'];?>" name="wachtwoord" style="width: 250px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 40px;" required placeholder="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" style="text-align: left; width: 120px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px;" for="woonplaats">Woonplaats:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="woonplaats" value="<?=$data['klant_woonplaats'];?>" name="woonplaats" style="width: 250px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 40px;" required placeholder="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="postcode" style="text-align: left; width: 120px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px;">Postcode:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postcode" value="<?=$data['klant_postcode'];?>" name="postcode" style="width: 250px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 40px;" required placeholder="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" style="text-align: left; width: 120px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px;" for="straat">Straat:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="straat" value="<?=$data['klant_straat'];?>" name="straat" style="width: 250px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 40px;" required placeholder="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" style="text-align: left; width: 120px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px;" for="huisnr">Huisnummer:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="huisnr" value="<?=$data['klant_huisnr'];?>" name="huisnr" style="width: 250px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 40px;" required placeholder="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" style="text-align: left; width: 120px; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px;" for="telnr">Telefoonnummer:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telnr" value="<?=$data['klant_telefoonnummer'];?>" name="telnr" style="width: 250px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 40px;" required placeholder="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" style="margin-left: 170px; margin-bottom: 20px;" class="btn btn-default" name="submit">Wijzigen</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to follow these steps on account php page,
1. Check if GET['wijzigen_id'] is set (You can print with print_r to confirm)
2. Check if select query is working
3. Check if your $data array is getting data from db
4. Try echo variables instead of